# Rails updating user settings using form_for and blank password fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following Hartl's Rails Tutorial, creating the edit user page. This is how I update in the update method:

```
@user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

where user_params is a method for strong parameters

In the user model I have also included the following line:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
```

Now, when I edit the user's name/email and submit the form with blank password fields, the user is successfully updated (the password stays the same instead of changing to a blank one). This is what I want. But why does that work? Is it something special about the form_for method? If I use rails console and try to update a user using the update_attributes method and a blank password, the object fails to save.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the `allow_blank` option which Rails in this case will ignore the password if it comes blank or nil.

Another approach I like is the one from [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) on which by using a method called `password_required?` they can handle multiple kinds of custom validations and gives you total control in case you need to overwrite, but that's just extra.